# Trying to hide the arrow on a select tag

Tags: html, css, interface

I have been having problems trying to hide the default arrow icon on the select tag

[image: http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/select_zpse4931c27.jpg]

CSS -

```
.toolbar .sort-by select {
background:url('/skin/frontend/baby/default/images/select_icon.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center right;
border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #9edef1;
font-family:'montserratregular', sans-serif; 
margin-left: 10px;

}
```

Regarding the image i have attached if you look at it closely there is a small background icon behind the default arrow icon. Not sure why it is not putting the background image on top of the default icon

Answer (score 1):

you can make a "select" div and another "drop-down" div, using some javascript.

as far as i know it wont work in css.

Comment: Weird there is a tutorial i'm trying to follow using only CSS http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: @clestcruz wow thats never thought of that, thats one of many examples of innovating interesting uses of things. now im going to try to help you understand it: you "hide" it by placing it past the edge of a div,(so that part isnt in the div. thats why you write "overflow: hidden;" i.e. it overflows the div's edge and the arrow gets included in "hidden") then place the img INSIDE the div so you see it. im not sure if it will work as a drop-down though try it.

Answer (score 1):

include `-webkit-appearance: none` in your css styling for the select tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is no css option to hide the arrow on the drop-down.